# Why can't I interact with some of my Image Buttons?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

everyone.

I'm trying to implement a card game in Xamarin.Forms.  At the start of a round the human player and AI player receive three cards each and four 'table cards' are positioned facing upwards.  A player can use one of his cards to capture one or more 'table cards' as long as the 'face values' of the card that he plays along with those that he takes from the table sum up to 15.

The implementation has gone well but when card Image Buttons are discarded to the table they refuse to be captured later if a valid opportunity comes along.  From simulator behaviour I know that the GetCombos method is seeing valid combinations but the foreach iteration within the AccessTableCards method seems to be ineffective.

At one stage cards discarded by the AI were capturable but cards discarded by the human player were not.  When I tried to condense the code to post it here the capability to capture cards that the AI had previously discarded was lost.

```
using MoreLinq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Scopa2
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        List<ImageButton> tableImgs;
        Card card1;
        Card card2;
        Card card3;
        Card card4;
        Card card5; 
        Card card6;
        List<Card> tableCards;
        Card humanCard1;
        Card humanCard2;
        Card humanCard3;
        List<Card> humanCards;
        Card aiCard1;
        Card aiCard2;
        Card aiCard3;
        List<Card> aiCards;
        List<ImageButton> aiImgs;
        ImageButton humanImg1 = new ImageButton();
        ImageButton humanImg2 = new ImageButton();
        ImageButton humanImg3 = new ImageButton();
        ImageButton tableCard1 = new ImageButton();
        ImageButton tableCard2 = new ImageButton();
        ImageButton tableCard3 = new ImageButton();
        ImageButton tableCard4 = new ImageButton();
        ImageButton tableCard5 = new ImageButton();
        ImageButton tableCard6 = new ImageButton();
        bool human1Pressed = false;
        bool human2Pressed = false;
        bool human3Pressed = false;
        bool table1Pressed = false;
        bool table2Pressed = false;
        bool table3Pressed = false;
        bool table4Pressed = false;
        bool table5Pressed = false;
        bool table6Pressed = false;
        List<ImageButton> humanImgs;
        int captureCount;

        public void OnHumanImg1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            human1Pressed = true;
            humanImg2.IsEnabled = false;
            humanImg3.IsEnabled = false;
            AccessTableImgs(humanCard1, humanImg1);
        }
        public void OnHumanImg2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            human2Pressed = true;
            humanImg1.IsEnabled = false;
            humanImg3.IsEnabled = false;
            AccessTableImgs(humanCard2, humanImg2);
        }
        public void OnHumanImg3Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            human3Pressed = true;
            humanImg1.IsEnabled = false;
            humanImg2.IsEnabled = false;
            AccessTableImgs(humanCard3, humanImg3);
        }
        public void OnTableImg1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table1Pressed = true;
            AdjudicateCapture(tableCard1, card1);
        }
        public void OnTableImg2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table2Pressed = true;
            AdjudicateCapture(tableCard2, card2);
        }

        public void OnTableImg3Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table3Pressed = true;
            AdjudicateCapture(tableCard3, card3);
        }

        public void OnTableImg4Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table4Pressed = true;
            AdjudicateCapture(tableCard4, card4);
        }
        public void OnTableImg5Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table5Pressed = true;
            AdjudicateCapture(tableCard5, card5);
        }
        public void OnTableImg6Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table6Pressed = true;
            AdjudicateCapture(tableCard6, card6);
        }
        async Task AccessTableImgs(Card i, ImageButton j)
        {
            GetCombos(out int x);
            if (x == 0)
            {
                if (human1Pressed == true)
                {
                    await FinishHumanMove(i, j);
                    human1Pressed = false;
                }
                else if (human2Pressed == true)
                {
                    await FinishHumanMove(i, j);
                    human2Pressed = false;
                }
                else if (human3Pressed == true)
                {
                    await FinishHumanMove(i, j);
                    human3Pressed = false;
                }
                AiTurn();
            }
            else if (x >= 1)
            {
                captureCount += (int)i.FaceValue;
                j.BorderWidth = 2.5;
                j.BorderColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                foreach (ImageButton k in tableImgs)
                {
                    k.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        public void GetCombos(out int number)
        {
            List<IList<int>> validCombos = new List<IList<int>>();
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tableCards.Count; i++)
            {
                numbers.Add((int)tableCards[i].FaceValue);
            }
            List<IList<int>> validCombos1 = numbers.Subsets().Where(a => a.Sum() == (15 - (int)humanCard1.FaceValue)).ToList();
            List<IList<int>> validCombos2 = numbers.Subsets().Where(a => a.Sum() == (15 - (int)humanCard2.FaceValue)).ToList();
            List<IList<int>> validCombos3 = numbers.Subsets().Where(a => a.Sum() == (15 - (int)humanCard3.FaceValue)).ToList();
            if (humanCards.Contains(humanCard1))
            {
                validCombos.AddRange(validCombos1);
            }
            if (humanCards.Contains(humanCard2))
            {
                validCombos.AddRange(validCombos2);
            }
            if (humanCards.Contains(humanCard3))
            {
                validCombos.AddRange(validCombos3);
            }
            number = validCombos.Count;
        }
        async Task FinishHumanMove(Card i, ImageButton j)
        {
            await DiscardCards(i, j);
            captureCount = 0;
        }
        public void AdjudicateCapture(ImageButton i, Card j)
        {
            captureCount += (int)j.FaceValue;
            if (captureCount < 15)
            {
                i.BorderWidth = 2.5;
                i.BorderColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                i.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            if (captureCount > 15)
            {
                captureCount = 0;
                foreach (ImageButton k in tableImgs)
                {
                    k.BorderWidth = 0;
                    k.IsEnabled = false;
                }
                foreach (ImageButton l in humanImgs)
                {
                    l.IsEnabled = true;
                    l.BorderWidth = 0;
                }
                human1Pressed = false;
                human2Pressed = false;
                human3Pressed = false;
                table1Pressed = false;
                table2Pressed = false;
                table3Pressed = false;
                table4Pressed = false;
                table5Pressed = false;
                table6Pressed = false;
            }
            if (captureCount == 15)
            {
                captureCount = 0;
                foreach (ImageButton k in tableImgs)
                {
                    k.IsEnabled = false;
                    k.BorderWidth = 0;
                }
                foreach (ImageButton l in humanImgs)
                {
                    l.IsEnabled = false;
                    l.BorderWidth = 0;
                }
                if (human1Pressed == true)
                {
                    humanImg1.Opacity = 0;
                    humanCards.Remove(humanCard1);
                    human1Pressed = false;
                }
                else if (human2Pressed == true)
                { 
                    humanImg2.Opacity = 0;
                    humanCards.Remove(humanCard2);
                    human2Pressed = false;
                }
                else if (human3Pressed == true)
                {
                    humanImg3.Opacity = 0;
                    humanCards.Remove(humanCard3);
                    human3Pressed = false;
                }
                if (table1Pressed == true)
                {
                    tableCard1.Opacity = 0;
                    tableImgs.Remove(tableCard1);
                    tableCards.Remove(card1);
                    table1Pressed = false;
                }
                if (table2Pressed == true)
                {
                    tableCard2.Opacity = 0;
                    tableImgs.Remove(tableCard2);
                    tableCards.Remove(card2);
                    table2Pressed = false;
                }
                if (table3Pressed == true)
                {
                    tableCard3.Opacity = 0;
                    tableImgs.Remove(tableCard3);
                    tableCards.Remove(card3);
                    table3Pressed = false;
                }
                if (table4Pressed == true)
                {
                    tableCard4.Opacity = 0;
                    tableImgs.Remove(tableCard4);
                    tableCards.Remove(card4);
                    table4Pressed = false;
                }
                if (table5Pressed == true)
                {
                    tableCard5.Opacity = 0;
                    tableImgs.Remove(tableCard5);
                    tableCards.Remove(card5);
                    table5Pressed = false;
                }
                if (table6Pressed == true)
                {
                    tableCard6.Opacity = 0;
                    tableImgs.Remove(tableCard6);
                    tableCards.Remove(card6);
                    table6Pressed = false;
                }
                AiTurn();
            }
        }
        async void AiTurn()
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            int num = rand.Next(aiImgs.Count);
            GetAiCombos(out int x);
            if (x == 0)
            {
                aiImgs[num].Source = CardID(aiCards[num]);
                await DiscardCards(aiCards[num], aiImgs[num]);
            }
            else if (x >= 1)
            {
                aiImgs[num].Source = CardID(aiCards[num]);
                await DiscardCards(aiCards[num], aiImgs[num]);
            }
            captureCount = 0;
            foreach (ImageButton i in humanImgs)
            {
                i.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        public void GetAiCombos(out int number)
        {
            List<IList<int>> aiValidCombos = new List<IList<int>>();
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tableCards.Count; i++)
            {
                numbers.Add((int)tableCards[i].FaceValue);
            }
            List<IList<int>> aiValidCombos1 = numbers.Subsets().Where(a => a.Sum() == (15 - (int)aiCard1.FaceValue)).ToList();
            List<IList<int>> aiValidCombos2 = numbers.Subsets().Where(a => a.Sum() == (15 - (int)aiCard2.FaceValue)).ToList();
            List<IList<int>> aiValidCombos3 = numbers.Subsets().Where(a => a.Sum() == (15 - (int)aiCard3.FaceValue)).ToList();
            if (aiCards.Contains(aiCard1))
            {
                aiValidCombos.AddRange(aiValidCombos1);
            }
            if (aiCards.Contains(aiCard2))
            {
                aiValidCombos.AddRange(aiValidCombos2);
            }
            if (aiCards.Contains(aiCard3))
            {
                aiValidCombos.AddRange(aiValidCombos3);
            }
            number = aiValidCombos.Count;
        }
        private async Task DiscardCards(Card i, ImageButton j)
        {
            if (!tableImgs.Contains(tableCard5))
            {
                tableCard5 = j;
                tableImgs.Add(tableCard5);
                tableCard5.IsEnabled = false;
                card5 = new Card(i.FaceValue, i.Suit);
                tableCards.Add(card5);
                if (aiImgs.Contains(j))
                {
                    aiImgs.Remove(j);
                }
                else if (humanImgs.Contains(j))
                {
                    humanImgs.Remove(j);
                }
                if (aiCards.Contains(i))
                {
                    aiCards.Remove(i);
                }
                else if (humanCards.Contains(i))
                {
                    humanCards.Remove(i);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tableCard5.TranslateTo(-2.2 * tableCard5.Width, 0, 500));
            }
            else if (tableImgs.Contains(tableCard5))
            {
                tableCard6 = j;
                tableCard6.IsEnabled = false;
                tableImgs.Add(tableCard6);
                card6 = new Card(i.FaceValue, i.Suit);
                tableCards.Add(card6);
                if (aiImgs.Contains(j))
                {
                    aiImgs.Remove(j);
                }
                else if (humanImgs.Contains(j))
                {
                    humanImgs.Remove(j);
                }
                if (aiCards.Contains(i))
                {
                    aiCards.Remove(i);
                }
                else if (humanCards.Contains(i))
                {
                    humanCards.Remove(i);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tableCard6.TranslateTo((2.2 * tableCard5.Width), 0, 500));
            }
        }
        private ImageSource CardID(Card card)
        {
            switch (card.FaceValue)
            {
                #region Aces
                case Card.Rank.Ace:
                    {
                        switch (card.Suit)
                        {
                            case Card.SuitType.Clubs:
                                {
                                    return ImageSource.FromResource("Scopa2.images.AC.jpg",
                    typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                                }
                            case Card.SuitType.Diamonds:
                                {
                                    return ImageSource.FromResource("Scopa2.images.AD.jpg",
                    typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                                }}}} //etc
```

Comment: There is way too much code here to really tell what is going on.  And I'm not sure what you mean by "interact" - are you saying the UI doesn't respond when selecting a "discarded" card?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly.   The UI doesn't respond when attempting to 'click' the cards that have been discarded.

Comment: So no coloured border or vanishing if the accumulated selections total fifteen points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix I am using for now

```
private async Task DiscardCards(Card i, ImageButton j)
        {
            if (!tableImgs.Contains(tableCard5))
            {
                tableCard5 = j;
                j.Clicked += OnTableImg5Clicked;
                tableImgs.Add(tableCard5);
                card5 = new Card(i.FaceValue, i.Suit);
                tableCards.Add(card5);
                if (aiImgs.Contains(j))
                {
                    aiImgs.Remove(j);
                }
                else if (humanImgs.Contains(j))
                {
                    humanImgs.Remove(j);
                }
                if (aiCards.Contains(i))
                {
                    aiCards.Remove(i);
                }
                else if (humanCards.Contains(i))
                {
                    humanCards.Remove(i);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tableCard5.TranslateTo(-2.2 * tableCard5.Width, 0, 500));
            }
            else if (tableImgs.Contains(tableCard5))
            {
                tableCard6 = j;
                j.Clicked += OnTableImg6Clicked;
                tableImgs.Add(tableCard6);
                card6 = new Card(i.FaceValue, i.Suit);
                tableCards.Add(card6);
                if (aiImgs.Contains(j))
                {
                    aiImgs.Remove(j);
                }
                else if (humanImgs.Contains(j))
                {
                    humanImgs.Remove(j);
                }
                if (aiCards.Contains(i))
                {
                    aiCards.Remove(i);
                }
                else if (humanCards.Contains(i))
                {
                    humanCards.Remove(i);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tableCard6.TranslateTo((2.2 * tableCard5.Width), 0, 500));
            }
        }
```